# How to route all internet requests through a proxy in docker swarm

Tags: docker, proxy

**tldr;** does docker swarm have a forceful and centered proxy setting that explicitly proxies all internet traffic in all services that is hosted in the cluster? Or any other tip of how to go about using a global proxy solution in a swarm cluster...?

**Obs!** this is not a question about a reversed proxy.

---

I have a docker swarm cluster (moving to Kubernatives as a solution is off-topic)

I have 3 managers and 3 workers, I label the workers accordingly to the expected containers they can host. The cluster only deploys docker swarm services, when I write "container" in this writing I'm referring to a docker swarm service container.

One of the workers is labelless, though active, and therefore does not host any containers to any service. If I would label the worker to allow it to host any container, then I will suffer issues in different firewalls that I don't always control, because the IP simply is not allowed.

This causes the problem for me that I can't do horizontal scaling, because when I add a new worker to the cluster, I also add a new IP that the requests can originate from. To update the many firewalls that would need to be updated because of a horizontal scaling is quite large, and simply not an option.

In my attempt to solve this on my own, I did what every desperate developer does and googled for a solution... and there is a simple and official documentation to be able to achieve this: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

I followed the environment variables examples on that page. Doing so did however not really help, none of the traffic goes through the proxy I configured. After some digging, I noticed that this is due to nodejs (all services are written using nodejs), ignoring the proxy settings set by the environment. To solve that nodejs can use these proxy settings, I have to refactor a lot of components in a lot of services... a workload that is quite trumendus and possibly dangerous to perform given the different protocols and ports I use to connect to different infrastructural services outside the cluster...

I expect there to be a better solution for this, I expect there to be a built in functionality that forces all internet access from the containers to go through this proxy, a setting I don't have to make in the code, in my implementations. I expect there to be a wrapping solution that I can control in a central manner.

*Now reading this again, I think maybe I should have tested the docker client configuration on the same page to see if it has the desired effect I'm requiring, but I assume they both would have the same outcome, being described on the same page with no noticeable difference written in the documentation.*

My question is, is there a solution, that I just don't seem to be able to find, that wraps the proxy functionality around all the services? or is it a requirement to solve these issues in the implementation itself?

---

My thought is to maybe depend on an image, that in its turn depends on the nodejs image that I use today - that is responsible for this wrapping functionality, though still on an implantation level. Doing so would however still force the inheriting of a distributed solution of this kind - if I need to change the proxy configurations, then I need to change them everywhere, and redeploy everything... given a less complex solution without an in common data access layer.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: TY for the link, I will try it out, but sorry for not making myself completely understood - I'm using multiple different types of protocols to be able to connect to a multitude of different infrastructure services. This solution you mention may work for HTTP gateways, but I doubt it will work for an snmp walk or database connection. Perhaps I simply just need to accept that I need a different type of proxy for different types of protocols, I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have much time before. I have limited experience running anything behind (normal) proxy because I left "large corporate life" long time ago :) ... anyway in your original post you were asking about connection from container to internet - in this case setting up proxy information in docker host config files is correct way to go. Commands as smnpwalk, curl, jdbc.. usually takes information from ENV VARS inside container and those vars should be imported base on your docker host conf file mentioned before

Comment: I do all these things through nodejs though. And yes, normally it is as you say, but there seem to be some exception in the case of nodejs, but honestly, I only tested with http, so I will dig deeper before I claim so to be the case.